# .Net Core display model validation with validation filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, unobtrusive-validation

I created a basic .Net Core Mvc application and I want to automatically set ModelState.IsValid for all my action here is the code of Validation Filter

```
public class ValidationFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

and here is my action code

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddUser(LoginRequestViewModel loginRequestViewModel)
    {
        return View(loginRequestViewModel);
    }
```

What should I return to display the errors in the asp-validation-for?
Without using any javascript code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the test of your code, global filtering can be achieved. Need to make ValidationFilter a global filter in startup.cs.

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(option=>
            {
                option.Filters.Add(new ValidationFilter());
            });
```

Then, create a model.

```
 public class LoginRequestViewModel
    {
        [MinLength(3)]
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
}
```

Define error messages in ValidationFilter.

```
public class ValidationFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Customize your error message
            string messages = string.Join("; ",context.ModelState.Values
                     .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                     .Select(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ErrorMessage) ? x.ErrorMessage : x.Exception.Message.ToString()));
            context.RouteData.Values.Add("mes", messages);
        }
        
        await next();
    }
}
```

In action, get  RouteData.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddUser(LoginRequestViewModel loginRequestViewModel)
        {
            ViewData["error"]= RouteData.Values["mes"];
            return View(loginRequestViewModel);
        }
```

Create AddUser.cshtml and use form.

```
 @model solution921.Controllers.LoginRequestViewModel
<form action="/home/AddUser" method="post">
@ViewData["error"]
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
    <span asp-validation-for="username"></span>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="" value="sub" />
</form>
```

It can return correct validation.
[image]

Comment: Correct. But what if I want to return custom result in ValidationFilter, I tried to return custom Result but can't display the error, it sends me to page with json format. I want to display the error from that JsonResult to my Span or Div.

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can pass error message from filter to action by routedata,and use viewdata to pass error message from action to view.