# asp.net core web api project how to with fluentvalidation auto-validation

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I want to use fluentvalidation to automatically verify exceptions, but I can’t do this now. If I put the Validator in the same one project, it will work, but if I put it Validator in another library, it will not work。
The following project one

```
public class TestValidator : AbstractValidator<WeatherForecast>
{
    public TestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Summary).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Username or email are required");
    }

}
```

The following project two

I said that registration and verification are placed in different projects, which leads to abnormal verification.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
    })
    .AddFluentValidation(options =>
    {
        options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change your startup to :

```
 .AddFluentValidation(options =>
{
    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<TestValidator>();
});
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer，I want to automatically scan and register all validation classes that implement the IValidator interface and automatically validate。I want to intercept the verification error message and return a custom error message, how can I do it?

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023438/fluentvalidation-how-to-register-all-validators-automatically-from-another-asse) may helpful.

Comment: You only need to register one of them, the others will be registered by default

Comment: thank you ,I want to intercept the verification error message and return a custom error message, how can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn’t your fluentvalidation your custom error message?

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982012/net-core-display-model-validation-with-validation-filter) may helpful.Implement ValidationFilter

Comment: i want to itercept WithMessage return a custom formatted error message,how to do it?

Comment: The error I return according to your scheme is like this  {
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|3fc13f08-4553143216e792ef.",
    "errors": {
        "Summary": [
            "Summary are required"
        ]
    }
}I hope to return an error exception in a custom format

Comment: I want to register a global error exception interceptor to return a custom error message，like this options.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilter()); but now it's wrong and can't work

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210281/why-do-we-no-longer-need-to-manually-validate-models-in-higher-versions-of-asp-n) may helpful.